# Does a Chicago to UAE flight fly over the Arctic Circle or go around it?

Tags: flight-path, polar, great-circle

I'm speaking about a flight from Chicago to UAE. Does it fly over the Arctic Circle or go around it?

Comment: Are you asking about specific flights, or flights at high latitudes in general? If in general; why should there be anything special about the arctic circle? There's plenty of airports north of it.

Comment: Am speaking about a flight from Chicago to UAE

Comment: [Have you had a look at the maps?](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=ord-dxb)

Answer (score 4):

A direct flight from Chicago to the UAE will come close, but not enter the Arctic Circle.

Some flights will take a slightly more northerly route due to winds and weather conditions, but most will not enter the Arctic Circle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 I can't find a direct flight to/from Dubai and Abu Dhabi, but Doha is close enough, see: https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QTR726/history/20200411/0000Z/KORD/OTHH